# Multiple Divs Show/Hide One at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide

I have a set of div's, What I want to do is when I click the read more button It shows the div "myContent" and hides the button for that particular container not all the divs with the same class name. and when I click the close button it hides the div (and because the button is there it should technically hide the button as well) and show the read more button again.

Whats happening right now is either all are showing or none are showing.
I am a newbie (using Jquery) Any help most appreciated.

The HTML

```
<!-- -->
<div class="member-content">
<div class="member-box">
    <div class="photo">
        <img src="" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="contact-details">
        <h3>Mike</h3>
        <span class="role">Member</span><br>
        <span class="telephone">07595 8674523</span><br>

    <a href="#" class="read-more">Read More</a>

    </div><!-- .contact-details -->
</div><!-- .member-box -->
</div><!-- .member-content -->


<div class="te contentDiv">
 <div class="myContent" style="display:none">
     <p>This Text is hidden</p>
    <a id="close_btn" href="#" class="close-more">Close</a>
 </div>    
</div>
<!-- -->

<!-- -->
<div class="member-content">
<div class="member-box">
    <div class="photo">
        <img src="" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="contact-details">
        <h3>Mike</h3>
        <span class="role">Member</span><br>
        <span class="telephone">07595 8674523</span><br>

    <a href="#" class="read-more">Read More</a>

    </div><!-- .contact-details -->
</div><!-- .member-box -->
</div><!-- .member-content -->


<div class="te contentDiv">
 <div class="myContent" style="display:none">
     <p>This Text is hidden</p>
    <a id="close_btn" href="#" class="close-more">Close</a>
 </div>    
</div>
<!-- -->

<!-- -->
<div class="member-content">
<div class="member-box">
    <div class="photo">
        <img src="" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="contact-details">
        <h3>Mike</h3>
        <span class="role">Member</span><br>
        <span class="telephone">07595 8674523</span><br>

    <a href="#" class="read-more">Read More</a>

    </div><!-- .contact-details -->
</div><!-- .member-box -->
</div><!-- .member-content -->


<div class="te contentDiv">
 <div class="myContent" style="display:none">
     <p>This Text is hidden</p>
    <a id="close_btn" href="#" class="close-more">Close</a>
 </div>    
</div>
<!-- -->
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please add jsfiddle or jsbin

Comment: You need to show us some Javascript using JSFiddle, you don't need to use jQuery to do this.

Comment: @DholakiyaAnkit so currently im trying something like this on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/a4fuV/ as you can see its not when i want happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this, Based on my understanding.

```
$('.read-more').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.member-content').next('.contentDiv').find('.myContent').show();
    $(this).hide();
});

$('.close-more').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.contentDiv').prev('.member-content').find('.read-more').show();
    $(this).closest('.myContent').hide();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/my7bM/)

Comment: @Satpal, I know.. this is probably why you have 25.5k points instead of mine 54 ;)

Comment: @Satpal Works great, Thank you! help Most appreciated.

Comment: @Satpal This works fine for standard content, How can I use this same function to target dynamically generated content?

Comment: @Zinox, I have updated code for event delegation(dynamically generated content) in the fiddle. See http://jsfiddle.net/my7bM/1/

Answer (score 2):

If I understand right [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vjnmh/1/) is what you are looking for :)

```
$('.read-more').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.member-content').next('.contentDiv').find('.myContent').fadeIn();
    $(this).hide();
});

$('.close-more').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.contentDiv').prev('.member-content').find('.read-more').fadeIn();
    $(this).closest('.myContent').hide();    
});
```

Comment: @dborghez Thank you! help Most appreciated.